# Save video after UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, nsurl

I would like to save video immediately after the video is captured with UIImagePickerController, so I'm using:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem", object:nil, queue:nil, usingBlock: { note in

            self.saveMovie()

        })
```

To save I generally use the delegate method

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        let videoPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL

        let stringVideoPath = videoPath.path

        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(stringVideoPath!, self, nil, nil)

        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        picker.view.superview?.removeFromSuperview()

    }
```

But I would like to bypass this. How can I get the `videoPath` without access to the `info` above and use `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` on my own?

Thanks